# SAS: generate abstractly long and large dataset

Tags: sas, performance-testing

Trying to do some performance testing
I can't figure out a macro

```
%generate(n_rows,n_cols);
```

that would generate a table with n_rows and n_cols, filled with random numbers/strings
I tried using this link:
http://bi-notes.com/2012/08/benchmark-io-performance/

But I quickly encounter a memory issue

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.  How big a table are you trying to produce?  What are your current hardware specs of the machine that is running SAS?  How much of that memory has SAS been configured to use?

Comment: How random do they need to be?  True random values, or just you don't care what they are and don't want them all the same?

Comment: all the same would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  I added a 2 input parameters.  So now you have a number of numerics and a number of characters.  Also the ability to define the output dataset name.

```
%macro generate(n_rows,n_num_cols,n_char_cols,outdata=test,seed=0);
data &outdata;
array nums[&n_num_cols];
array chars[&n_char_cols] $;
temp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
do i=1 to &n_rows;
    do j=1 to &n_num_cols;
        nums[j] = ranuni(&seed);
    end;
    do j=1 to &n_char_cols;
        chars[j] = substr(temp,ceil(ranuni(&seed)*18),8);
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i j temp;
run;

%mend;

%generate(10,10,10,outdata=test);
```

Comment: You could skip a step and do `chars[j] = put(ranuni(0), best.)` for the characters.

Comment: Thanks! Hey quick question. How do you prevent entreprise guide from loading the results in the Output Data Window so my computer doesn't hang after creating the dataset?

Comment: That's an option under Results (Automatically open data or results when generated).  You can also change the maximum number of datasets to link to zero.

Comment: I would add a seed (and a seed parameter) so you can recreate the identical dataset - depending on what you're doing for performance checking having the identical random dataset could be helpful.